# A is not invertible, but A * 1.00001 is

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm having an odd problem, and I assume it's coming from numerical accuracy (but am not sure).

I have a sparse matrix (data at the end)

```
x
Out[25]: 
<11250x11250 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 44547 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

and a vector

```
z = np.zeros((x.shape[0]))
z[idx] = 0.1
```

I'm trying to solve

```
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve
F = spsolve(x, z)
```

but I get

```
scipy.sparse.linalg.dsolve.linsolve.MatrixRankWarning: Matrix is exactly singular
```

I'm pretty certain that `x` *should* allow inversion, and I will describe it afterwards. However, indicative is already that

```
spsolve(x* 1.00000001, z)
Out[53]: array([-0., -0., -0., ..., -0., -0., -0.])
spsolve(x/ 1.00000001, z)
Out[54]: array([-0., -0., -0., ..., -0., -0., -0.])
```

If `x` is not invertible, neither should be a linear scaling of the whole matrix.

### So what's going on here? Are these floating-point problems?

---

**Background**

I have a matrix `A` that satisfies typical properties of a continuous-time generator matrix corresponding to a transition matrix:

- diagonals are negative
- off-diagonals are non-negative
- rows add up to one

I then want to compute the stationary distribution. I do that by creating a vector of zeros, `z`. For an arbitrary index `idx`, I set `z[idx] = 0.1`. I fix `A[idx] = 0`. Then, the (not normalized) stationary distribution `g` can be solved as

```
A.T g = z
```

In the previous problem, the adjusted `A` with `A[idx] = 0` is labelled `x`.

---

**Data**

I'm not sure how to provide the data behind `x`. The problem occurs when the matrices are really large, so I can't just paste the contents here. The data generation problem is long and complicated and hence also isn't suitable for provision.

The best I came up with is storing and uploading the (sparse) [npz](https://ufile.io/e38aq), which can be loaded via `scipy.sparse.load_npz`. Please let me know if there's a better way.

---

I've also plotted the largest singular values associated with `A`:

[image: singular values]

However, it's unclear how much single-peakedness of these singular values predicts numerical stability. Next are the largest singular values for a matrix that I do manage to invert, they appear similarly flat:

[image: sv, working case]

Comment: Finding the stationary distribution is equivalent to finding that eigenvector of A which has eigenvalue one. One possible difficulty is if the structure of A is such that this eigenvector contains zeros. If you pick your 'idx' such that you hit one of those zeros, I expect that could be a source of problems. Alternatively, I'm wondering if you can just set A[idx, idx]=1, after zeroing the rest of that row, to improve numerical conditioning. The fact that scaling your "x" matrix changes the behaviour of spsolve() is indeed interesting.

Comment: @rwp I tried `x[idx, idx] = 1`, to no avail.

Comment: Can you describe the stochastic process that underlies your "A"? Is it possible that this process doesn't have an equilibrium, or that for sufficiently large dimensions there is more than one eigenvalue which is (to numerical precision) unity? For example, the transition matrix might have some form of limit cycle. Have you looked at the eigenvalue spectrum when the number of dimensions is small enough to compute the SVD?

Comment: @rwp I have three state variables: `a`, `b`, `c`. There are no transitions across `c`. `a` follows an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process. `b` either increases or decreases at each grid point. For high `b`, it decreases and for low `b`, it increases, the speed depending on `a`. I have already noticed that when the diffusion of `b` happens at faster rate, these numerical problems happen less often.

Comment: I have no prior knowledge on using eigenvalue spectrum for diagnostics in this environment. Do you have a link for me to follow-up on that? Btw. to the extent that this is a diagnostical problem, I suppose all these comments could already be formulated as an answer.

Comment: Since both `a` and `b` are diffusion processes, there is four potential transitions for each state. (It turns out to be three max because `b` is exclusively increasing or decreasing). Whenever I remove any of those four transitions, `x` also becomes invertible... I can't find any logic to what's *structurally* causing it, which is why I was handwaivingly suspicious of *numerical inaccuracies*

Answer (score 2):

One sanity check that you could try is to compute the eigenvalue spectrum of your A matrix. The stationary distribution of your stochastic process is essentially that eigenvector of the transition matrix which has eigenvalue unity. However, in order to have an well-defined equilibrium distribution, there must be a unique eigenvalue of unity and all other eigenvalues must have (real parts) that are less than one.
So, if you compute the singular value decomposition of A, the diagonal matrix you obtain will reveal something about the stability of the equilibrium state and the multiple timescales over the system decays to that equilibrium.
If your stochastic process is well behaved, then plotting a graph of the singular values in decreasing sorted order of magnitude should have an isolated peak at n=0. If, however, there is a more gradual fall-off, then this is a sign that the system may settle only very slowly into equilibrium, and will probably be numerically ill-conditioned as you increase the dimensionality of your problem.

Another thing worth checking for your [Ornstein-Uhlenbeck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process) process is that as you increase the dimension of your system you may need to reduce the effective timestep of your transition matrix. This is reminiscent of the need to reduce the timestep of the numerical solution of a parabolic differential equation to correspond to the spatial lengthscale of the grid on which one describes a diffusive process, if one is to avoid numerical instabilities.

Comment: I've added my singular values both for the non-working case, and another simpler one where it does work. From my judgement, I guess the sv are not really single-peaked for neither case.